# How to redirect role based login to a nwidart module of Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am stuck somewhere in creating Multi Auth Laravel Project. I setup the project on Laravel 8 and I have done Jetstream, Fortify setup.

I have created 4 [nwidart Modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules)

1. SuperAdmin
2. Admin
3. User
4. Meeting

Database already linked, User role already created, I am able to login role-based with different user dashboard.  My question is.

I want to redirect users to a specific Module after login. If SuperAdmin logged in he should redirect to the above module pages (I already created pages and those are working fine). Here are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So if you are using Jetstream you would probably have a file called AuthenticatedSessionController.php which should handle the login

There is a method called store

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

You could change the logic here so that where it has `intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)`

You could change it to:

```
$route = auth()->user()->isSuperAdmin() ? route('superadmin.index') : route('normaluser.index');

return redirect()->intended($route);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I left that project